# Images path has been change when htacess command custom error page

Tags: image, .htaccess, custom-error-pages

I've been completed created custom error page (403.html and 404.html). Then I've uploaded it to host. I will view page, all css and images has show, it's completely work.

Then I write htaccess custom error page with these code.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errordocs/403.htm
ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.htm
```

then I've uploaded it to server. And I test it.

When I access page to get error 403 (ex.www.domain.com/images/) It will show the 403.htm
page, but the images was not show, I check images url, it's wrong url that I created on the 403.html

- The url of images on 403.html that created by me is

  `www.domain.com/images/images/403-text.png`
- The url of images on 403.html that command error page by .haccess is
  `http://www.kbyala.ac.th/images/images/403-text.png`

I don't know what's wrong. How to fix this problem. Help me please :'(

Answer (score 1):

in your 403.html page, specify url as

```
<img src="/images/images/403-text.png" />
```

where / means root folder of your website, so /images/images/403-text.png is relative to your website's root folder.

dont include www.domain.com in the src attr.

Comment: The backslash in front did it for me.  Thank you!